# Concatenation of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I want a function that takes two lists of any type and returns one (i.e. `f:: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]`). Basically, too produce the 'concatenation' of the two input lists.

e.g.

```
> f [[1,2,3], [123]] [[4,5,6], [3,7]]
[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,3,7], [123,4,5,6], [123,3,7]]
```

I currently have got this far with it:

```
f _ [] = []
f [] _ = []
f (xs:xss) (ys:yss) = ((xs ++ ys) : [m | m <- f [xs] yss])
```

But this doesn't take into account `xss` and is wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a Cartesian product, so you can simply use one list comprehension to do everything.

```
Prelude> let xs = [[1,2,3], [123]]
Prelude> let ys = [[4,5,6], [3,7]]
Prelude> [x ++ y | x <- xs, y <- ys]
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,3,7],[123,4,5,6],[123,3,7]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import Control.Applicative

(++) <$> [[1,2,3], [123]] <*> [[4,5,6], [3,7]]
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,3,7],[123,4,5,6],[123,3,7]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
f l1 l2 = [x ++ y | x <- l1, y <- l2]
```

Comment: How did I miss this!?! Kicking myself. Basic basic stuff!

Answer (score 2):

In [`Alternative`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html#2):

```
import Control.Applicative

f :: (Applicative f, Alternative g) => f (g a) -> f (g a) -> f (g a)
f = liftA2 (<|>)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f a b = map concat . sequence $ [a,b]
```

Scales up for combining any number of lists.